# JerseyTest set a property for ContainerRequestContext

Tags: java, java-8, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-test-framework

Using `JerseyTest` framework, how can I set a property in `ContainerRequestContext` to be used during my test session

I try adding into the `ResourceConfig` before the run of the test

```
ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig();
rc.property("hello", "world");
```

And in the Request

```
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = target().path("test/custom_header");
        Response response = client.target(target.getUri())
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .property("hello", "world")
```

But always in my ContainerRequestContext filter the property is null

```
context.getProperty("hello")//always null
```

Any idea how can I set a property during the test?

Regards

Comment: You can use another filter with a higher priority.